# SQL Server : single row result with 2 calls to child table

Tags: sql-server-2008, parent-child

I've searched but am perhaps not phrasing my search terms correctly. I could really use some design help with the following simple query.

I have a Parent Tables that lists games

```
GAMENUM     HOMEID     AWAYID
1             25         29
2             12         17
3             13         12
```

Team Table

```
TEAMID    TEAMNAME
12        Blue 
13        Yellow
17        Red
25        Pink
29        White
```

What I need is a query to get a list like

```
GAMENUM    HOMEID    AWAYID   HOMETEAM     AWAYTEAM
1          25        29       Pink         White
2          12        17       Blue         Red
3          13        12       Blue
```

If there is no associated team code with an ID I would still want the game record returned, but with a NULL for the HOMETEAM or AWAYTEAM name if not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.GAMENUM, p.HOMEID, p.AWAYID, t1.TEAMNAME [HOMETEAM], t2.TEAMNAME [AWAYTEAM]
FROM [Parent] p
LEFT JOIN Team t1 ON t1.TEAMID = p.HOMEID
LEFT JOIN Team t2 ON t2.TEAMID = p.AWAYID
```

Test case:

```
WITH [Parent] AS (SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 [GAMENUM], 25 [HOMEID], 29 [AWAYID] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 12, 17 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 13, 12) as [Parent]),

[Team] AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 12 [TEAMID], 'Blue' [TEAMNAME] UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 'Yellow' UNION ALL
    SELECT 17, 'Red' UNION ALL
    SELECT 25, 'Pink' UNION ALL
    SELECT 29, 'White') as [Team])

SELECT p.GAMENUM, p.HOMEID, p.AWAYID, t1.TEAMNAME [HOMETEAM], t2.TEAMNAME [AWAYTEAM]
FROM [Parent] p
LEFT JOIN Team t1 ON t1.TEAMID = p.HOMEID
LEFT JOIN Team t2 ON t2.TEAMID = p.AWAYID
```

Please check **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ce79/1)** for test case results

Comment: Guess you meant `t1.TEAMNAME AS HOMETEAM, t2.TEAMNAME AS AWAYTEAM` ?

Comment: Hi Guys, I'm a little confused over the whole section above the last four lines. There are hundreds of teams and thousands of games in my planned usage.  To get a query that shows all the games and the team names in the games,would be impossible to do in the above example?

Comment: Looks like I can make it work with the addition of the Distinct element

Comment: Sorry @JustJeffy, I changed my answer